# Emacs ediff error "no newline at end of file"

Tags: emacs, diff, newline

On Debian Wheezy, Emacs 23.3.1, running ediff-files with a file that is missing a newline at the end results in the error `\ No newline at end of file` (I hope that's the correct translation; it's German `\ Kein Zeilenumbruch am Dateiende.` on my computer.)

Is it possible to have just a warning instead, so that I can see the diff and work on it (and fix the missing newline)?  It's just a bit tedious to first have ediff fail, then open the file, add the newline, ediff again.

Comment: What do you mean by ediff 'erroring' and 'failing'? Do you want to treat a missing newline at the end of a file as a difference, or not (in which case you can set `ediff-diff-options` to `"-w"` to ignore whitespace differences)?

Comment: With "failing" I mean that instead of getting a diff, `ediff-files` stops with the error message `Errors in diff output.  Diff output is in #<buffer *ediff-diff*>` and a buffer `*ediff-errors*` pops up with `\ Kein Zeilenumbruch...`.  And yes, I'd prefer if the problem was shown to me as a warning and then the diff would be displayed.  With `-w`, the error still occurs.  (Still, this wouldn't help if I wanted to look for whitespace differences.)

Comment: OK, I see what you mean now, I get the same error if I set my language to German. As you say in your answer, Emacs is expecting the output of diff to be in English. I've suggested another workaround.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try changing the value of the variable `ediff-diff-ok-lines-regexp` to include the German text ("Kein Zeilenumbruch am Dateiende"):

```
(setq ediff-diff-ok-lines-regexp
      (concat
       "^\\("
       "[0-9,]+[acd][0-9,]+\C-m?$"
       "\\|[] "
       "\\|---"
       "\\|.*Warning *:"
       "\\|.*No +newline"
       "\\|.*missing +newline"
       "\\|.*Kein +Zeilenumbruch +am +Dateiende"
       "\\|^\C-m?$"
       "\\)"))
```

**Update:** Looking at the source code, it does seem that Ediff doesn't make any attempt to deal with the issue of localization of messages from `diff`. It should also be possible to work around this by wrapping `diff` in a shell script, e.g:

```
#!/bin/bash
LANG=C diff $*
```

..then customising the `ediff-diff-program` to call the wrapper instead:

```
(setq ediff-diff-program "~/bin/my-diff.sh")
```

Other code in the Emacs source directory lisp/vc does seem to handle this, for example `vc-hg-state`:

```
(defun vc-hg-state (file)
  "Hg-specific version of `vc-state'."
   ...
        (with-output-to-string
          (with-current-buffer
              standard-output
            (setq status
                  (condition-case nil
                      ;; Ignore all errors.
              (let ((process-environment
                 ;; Avoid localization of messages so we
                 ;; can parse the output.
                 (append (list "TERM=dumb" "LANGUAGE=C")
                     process-environment)))
   ...
```

It seems a bit strange that Ediff doesn't also do this, but perhaps I'm missing something.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about this variable.  Now we only have to add a regex for every possible language…

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I found out what's wrong, and sadly, it's quite obvious: my environment has `LANG=de`, therefore when Emacs invokes `diff`, the warning message is returned in German as well, and Emacs, not recognising this “unkown” message, fails.

Starting emacs with `LANG=C emacs` works around this problem.  However, I consider it a (quite silly) bug of emacs to make assumption on the user's language being English.

Comment: That seems worth reporting. `M-x report-emacs-bug`

Comment: This is now more then ten years ago, and I still get bitten by this.